# unable to execute: apt-get update

Tags: networking, apt, ethernet

I am trying to execute "apt-get update" where the system is taking long time and not doing anything.

Ubuntu-16.04

I can ping google.com
attached ifconfig display
ping response

Please point me in the right direction

all the commands are running in root user

--apt-get update--

```
root@ravi-ubundu:/home/ravi# apt-get update
0% [Connecting to gb.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::11)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::11)]
```

--ifconfig--

```
root@ravi-ubundu:/home/ravi# ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8d:de:f3
          inet addr:192.168.0.155  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:c7d:9bd9:0:61b1:4d00:dc9:8f14/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:c7d:9bd9:0:8f27:1145:2168:8c0d/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fdb0:6eb3:3be5:0:b5f0:b2d:55b1:6de5/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fdb0:6eb3:3be5:0:61b1:4d00:dc9:8f14/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:c7d:9bd9:0:f0ba:8d3d:befd:94ea/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::3cdf:4b12:4371:2c3a/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fdb0:6eb3:3be5:0:5f08:c4d0:8e3d:59a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:c7d:9bd9:0:b5f0:b2d:55b1:6de5/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fdb0:6eb3:3be5:0:aa18:5aa0:198:5ad0/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1274 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:979 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:129718 (129.7 KB)  TX bytes:154341 (154.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:24015 (24.0 KB)  TX bytes:24015 (24.0 KB)

root@ravi-ubundu:/home/ravi# ping google.co.uk
PING google.co.uk (216.58.204.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr25s12-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.204.35): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=19.3 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s12-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.204.35): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=18.1 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s12-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.204.35): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=22.1 ms
^C
```

Comment: So technically apt-get IS executing. Have you tried to choose an other archive ? You could try an other local one or main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is having a problem with the `IPv6` settings.  You can disable it with:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Append this:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Run this command:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Details at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsingSlowIPv6IPv4

In the future if you wish to reenable `IPv6` just remove the appended lines from your `/etc/syst.conf` file.

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad it worked.  Consider clicking the grey checkmark as a helpful solution so that others having a similar issue can easier find answers that works.

Comment: One more quick question do I need to execute: 'sudo sysctl -p' after every restart?

Comment: @RaviJaganathan No.  Executing the commandline is just for making the change effective without rebooting.  The `/etc/syst.conf` file is loaded at bootup.  That's why I added a reference of how to cancel the change.