# apt-get update will not connect

Tags: networking, apt, updates, 16.10

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 Server VM on a Proxmox 4.4-1 server. Network for VM is going through my bridged interface (LAN). My pfSense router is also on the same physical host using the same bridged interface as LAN. My ISP modem is set to bridged mode.

Whenever I run "apt-get update" it hangs on "0% [Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.161)] [Connecting to securit"

I've done packet captures on LAN and WAN interfaces that show I am only sending SYN packets, not receiving anything from the ubuntu servers listed above.

I have my pfSense firewall NAT and Rules setup properly, the laptop I'm typing this on is using the same router and on the same subnet/VLAN as the VM.

I've also spoken with my ISP and they assured me there were no errors on their modem tests.

If you need any more information, please ask. I'm sick of this problem and want to know what the source is.

Thanks!

[imgur gallery with requested screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP8KB.jpg)

```
defau1t@defMINE:~$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Could not connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease
Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease
Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease
Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease  Could not connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
defau1t@defMINE:~$
```

Here's the output

```
defau1t@defMINE:~$ ./scripttest.sh | tee scripttest.out
wget1
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 16:13:38--  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Resolving ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.152, 91.189.88.149, 91.189.88.161, ...
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 16:22:23--  (try: 2)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 16:31:08--  (try: 3)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 16:39:56--  (try: 4)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 16:48:43--  (try: 5)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 16:57:32--  (try: 6)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80...     failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 17:06:22--  (try: 7)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 17:15:11--  (try: 8)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 17:24:03--  (try: 9)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 17:32:54--  (try:10)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 17:41:47--  (try:11)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 17:50:40--  (try:12)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 17:59:32--  (try:13)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 18:08:25--  (try:14)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 18:17:17--  (try:15)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 18:26:10--  (try:16)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 18:35:02--  (try:17)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 18:43:55--  (try:18)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 18:52:47--  (try:19)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:01:40--  (try:20)  http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.161|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (ca.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.162|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Giving up.

wget2
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:10:22--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.26, 91.189.91.23
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:14:45--  (try: 2)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:19:09--  (try: 3)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:23:34--  (try: 4)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:27:59--  (try: 5)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:32:26--  (try: 6)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:36:53--  (try: 7)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:41:21--  (try: 8)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:45:50--  (try: 9)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:50:19--  (try:10)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:54:51--  (try:11)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 19:59:21--  (try:12)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 20:03:51--  (try:13)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 20:08:22--  (try:14)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 20:12:52--  (try:15)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 20:17:22--  (try:16)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 20:21:53--  (try:17)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 20:26:23--  (try:18)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 20:30:53--  (try:19)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-03-26 20:35:24--  (try:20)  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Giving up.

Ping test
PING 91.189.88.152 (91.189.88.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.88.152: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=149 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.152: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=149 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.152: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=150 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.152: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=149 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.152: icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=151 ms

--- 91.189.88.152 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 149.161/150.046/151.045/0.772 ms
PING 91.189.91.23 (91.189.91.23) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.91.23: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=99.6 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.91.23: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=85.5 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.91.23: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=84.5 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.91.23: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=84.6 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.91.23: icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=84.8 ms

--- 91.189.91.23 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 84.598/87.861/99.698/5.939 ms
dnstest
us.archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.23
us.archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.26
us.archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1562::19
us.archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1562::16
ca.archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.88.161
ca.archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.88.152
ca.archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.88.162
ca.archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.88.149
ca.archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1360:8001::17
ca.archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1360:8001::21
ca.archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1560:8001::14
ca.archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1560:8001::11
```

Comment: Will you answer this question?  Are you saying it just hangs forever and never time out with an error message?  If it times out can you make a reference to how long it takes to time out?  Also, will you capture the text on your screen starting out with the actual command all the way to the last line where it's hung up if it just hangs and never stops, or to the prompt after it has eventually exited with an error?

Comment: Pictures added.

Comment: I can't make out what is happening from the picture.  Run this command: `sudo apt update`.  Please don't take a picture of the screen.  Copy the text that is on the screen then paste it to your question.  Please include in the copy, **Starting from the Typed command to the last line of the text**.  The last line will be your command prompt... or wherever it stops and hangs.  You didn't say if it hangs forever.  Give the command 5 or 10 minutes to respond.

Comment: Failed apt-get added

Comment: Great!  Will you do the same for these commands:
**(1)** `wget --spider http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease`
**(2)** `wget --spider http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/InRelease`
**(3)** `ping -c5 91.189.88.152;ping -c5 91.189.91.23`
**(4)** `host us.archive.ubuntu.com&&host ca.archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: The first one is on try 5 of all DNS entries for ca.archive.ubuntu.com... Should I stop and move on?

Comment: Please let the commands time out and show the full output of the commands.  The details and amount of time are important.  It would take too much dialog for me to ask about each element.

Comment: Because it may take a long time to copy and paste each of the commands and wait for the output, use this link:
[scripttest.sh.txt](http://www.apollo3.com/script/scripttest.sh.txt).  Copy and paste text to a script file.  Run the script like this: `./scripttest.sh | tee scripttest.out`.  Then append the output (scripttest.out) to your question.  This way you can run the one command and wait how long it may take to time out, and have the full content.

Comment: Good idea, thanks for doing that. Sidenote: it was on attempt number 12 when you posted that... Does wget have a max number of tries?

Comment: Yes.  I don't know what the max is, but it'll time out.  I'm almost certain the output should clarify what is broken.

Comment: Turns out it's 20 attempts. Output in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I created the following:
[image: Bridges in Proxmox]

vmbr0 has the following properties:

```
Ip Address: 10.2.0.240
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway 10.2.0.1
autostart: Yes
Bridge Ports: ens33
```

vmbr1 has the following properties:

```
autostart: yes
Bridge Ports: ens37
```

vmbr2 has the following properties:

```
autostart: yes
Bridge Ports: ens38
```

Due to an issue, with kvm and vmware, I was not able to successfully create a VM, though I was able to create and implement an lxc container. Once activated:
1. Received an IP address from DHCP.
2. Able to successfully run the command: `apt-get update`

Overall, it appears the issue may be with the firewall rules. Though in order to eliminate that as a suspect, I recommend to exclude the IP address of the Virtual machine and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for all your work, it turned out to be the VirtIO network device I had set for the VM. Not sure why this was a problem but once I switched it to an Intel E1000 device it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Disable ipv6:

Edit your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.

Append this:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Run this command to make it immediately become in effect:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

This is taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/881603/29012)

The problem happens when an ISP configuration to force ipv6 connections.

Comment: I looked at that question and the issue was he was getting IPv6 addresses for his update repositories. I am not. Sidenote: switching the interface to Intel E1000 fixed it.... I have no idea why that worked but it did.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm curious.  Did you try the disable of the ipv6?  I'm seen occasions where switching the Network Adapter made a difference.  I incurred problems after the switch and it worked again.  That was before learning about the disable of the ipv6.  Also, I've seen numerous occasions where the ipv6 state doesn't matter with several computers on the same network, while problems with a single computer.  All in all, I'm glad you are up and running!

Comment: I did try to disable IPv6 but it still didn't work. Which is when I was like "Hail mary!" and switched to the Intel interface. I also just re-enabled IPv6 and it still worked with Intel (I also tried switching back to virtIO after it had worked with Intel, still failed). So I guess using virtIO NICs for virtual machines is not going to be a thing until I figure out what the hell went wrong with it. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: It's a pleasure!  Thanks for the additional valuable info.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like a network related configuration issue of some sort.

First, let's review the results from `ifconfig`. Things to note from these results are the inet and netmask entries.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.2.0.220  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::226:2dff:fe46:c03b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:26:2d:46:c0:3b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 282331  bytes 209953345 (209.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 168130  bytes 106104466 (106.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Though with the above information, it would appear I have something incorrect with my interfaces file. Even though, I am able to ping the address from machines inside my network and even gain ssh access to it, the netmask is wrong for my subnet.

Now, let's review my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.2.0.220
        mask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.2.0.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

It would appear I have misspelled the entry for netmask as mask. 
I make the change, and I choose to restart my machine:
`sudo shutdown -r 0`

When it comes back up, I run: `ifconfig` which provides the following:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.2.0.220  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.2.0.255
        inet6 fe80::226:2dff:fe46:c03b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:26:2d:46:c0:3b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 282331  bytes 209953345 (209.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 168130  bytes 106104466 (106.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If you discovered something similar, then at this point you should be to complete:
`sudo apt-get update`

If still having difficulties, review the VM configuration settings from the Host side. Verifying the network is connected to the connected, and that it is not host-only.

Or it could be related to the mirror that was chosen, when installed, perhaps it is down, or some other glitch.

Could look at having a new sources.list generated:
[Ubuntu Sources List Generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)

After selecting the repositories and PPA's to include, click on the Generate List button at the bottom of the page.

It generates the code for each section to download and replace your current files, so make backups before proceeding.

```
curl https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/txt/yakkety/sources_SomeLongNumber.txt | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't curl, wget, nc, anything to any web server from this vm.

Comment: @robin5693     sounds like a network configuration issue of some sort. If applicable, please edit your post to include screenshots of the network config for the vm and the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` file and the results of running ifconfig.

Comment: Okay they've been added

Comment: Have you tried changing the Network Device (net0) on your VM, from vmbr2 to vmbr0, or are you able too. I could be mistaken, though neither vmbr1 or vmbr2, appear to have any network associated with them.

Comment: In proxmox, vmbr0 is the management interface which is bridged from eth0. vmbr1 and vmbr2 are bridged from physical interfaces eth1 and eth2. eth1 is directly connected from my ISP modem, and eth2 is my LAN interface.

Comment: from the virtual machine, are you able to ping 10.0.0.19 and 10.0.0.1?  What is the IP of vmbr2, and are you able to ping that address?

Comment: I'm able to ping both 19 and 1. The IP of my router on vmbr2 is 10.0.0.1, that's also where all of my LAN stuff is going through.

Comment: Does your dhcp server provide gateway IP address?  Could always  set a static ip and try the following:   `auto ens18 \n iface ens18 inet static\n address 10.0.0.112\n netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 10.0.0.1\n dns-nameservers 10.0.0.1`   -- added in \n to signify where a new line should start, should you wish to try, then restart your vm.

Comment: I tried setting a static IP and it still happens....

Comment: Are you using an internal DNS server? or using the IP address of the iSP router, to forward DNS Requests? If internal, make sure a forwarder is set that points to the ISP router address - if 10.0.0.1 is that address.

Comment: I have my router set as a DNS resolver with google's DNS servers. But it's not DNS because my laptop uses the router as its DNS server and it works just fine. Sidenote: just created a new VM using a NAT network interface and it can reach the internet but I have no idea where it got its IP (10.0.2.15) from and I can't ping my router, or the hypervisor from it.

Comment: This is most likely wrong, I am not familiar with Proxmox, though if there is a bridge for both eth1 and eth2, should they not both have at least an internal IP address assigned or at least eth2, much like vmbr0 and eth0?

Comment: As far as I know, vmbrN interfaces are virtual bridges that can accept and forward connections from both the virtual side and whichever physical ports are assigned to it. The devices that actually use the interface are what set and ask for IP addresses

Comment: It will be a little while before I respond again, attempting to install proxmox, to see if can simulate what is occurring.