# Not able to ping from AWS EC2 instance

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2, amazon-ec2

In my AWS EC2 instance, I hosted my website few days back.  The website has apache, php, mysql and elasticsearch installed.  Few days back I updated my site with SSL certification.  I configured a security group include inbound to:

```
HTTP, SSH and HTTPS
```

My website is rendering properly and I am able to ssh into my EC2 instance.  However, when i tried to update some python libraries, I could not do so - I get a `connection timed out error after a minute`.  So is `apt update` command.  When I tried `ping www.google.com` nothing happens.

I tried adding custom ICMP rule as given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance) in my security group.  However, it did not help.

I tried appending ipv6 conf in `/etc/systyl.conf` as given in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881597/unable-to-execute-apt-get-update/881603#881603).  This too did not help.

I am completely new to this and I am DIY person.  I am not sure how to proceed further and don't want to meddle with.  Can someone help?

Comment: Security Groups add https and select anywhere

Comment: @GHOST  Thank you...I did that...but didn't work.  I had to change parameters on my VPU to allow all traffic and it started working.  Not sure whether it is correct or not....

Comment: when you type your ip address its that show default apache2 home page?

Comment: @GHOST yes it does...since i have configured an index page as the default page for my url, that page gets loaded.

Comment: make sure http and https are select from any where and then restart apache2 and check